Moment existence under weak $L^1$-convergence
Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a real-valued sequence in $L^1(\Omega, \mu)$ with $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d,$ which converges weakly to a function $f \in L^1(\Omega, \mu).$ Assume that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the $q$-th moment of $f_n$ exists for some $q \geq 1$, meaning
$$ \int_{\Omega} |x|^q |f_n(x)| \, d\mu(x) < \infty.$$
Can we conclude that the $q$-th moment exists for the weak limit $f$ too, that is
$$ \int_{\Omega} |x|^q |f(x)| \, d\mu(x) < \infty.$$
My conjecture would be yes. But how can one prove that? I know the weak lower semicontinuity of convex functions which is applicable to $L^1$-functions but this would not work here. And if it is not true, under which conditions this would be true?

No. Pick any $f$ that is continuous, in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, and that does not admit $q$-th moment. (Say, $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ when $|x| \geq 1$ and $f(x) = 1$ otherwise. Then $f$ does not admit $q$-th moment for any $q \geq 1$.) Let $f_n = 1_{\{|x| \leq n\}} f$. Then $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$-norm and $f_n$ admits $q$-th moment for any $q \geq 1$.

I see, thanks. And under which additional conditional this would hold? I had thought of uniform boundedness of the $q$-th moments, $ \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{\Omega} |x|^q |f_n(x)| , dx < \infty$?

@kumquat That would be sufficient. Using Hahn-Banach, you can change from weak $L^1$ convergence to convergence in $L^1$ norm. Passing to a subsequence, we can then assume the convergence is a.e. Then the result follows from Fatou’s lemma. (Note that the $q$-th moment of $f$ may not be the limit of $q$-moments of $f_n$, just that it exists and is bounded by the supremum of $q$-th moments of $f_n$.)

I suppose we would use here the Hahn-Banach theorem, in the form of Mazur's lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%27s_lemma), for example?

@kumquat That is correct.
